# react add object to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a component I have:

```
constructor() {
   super();
     this.state = {
     lists: [], 
     items: {}  
    };
 }

 handleAddList(s) {
  
    var temp= this.state.lists.slice(0,this.state.lists.length);
    temp.push(s);

    this.setState({lists: temp},function(){
    
    var toAdd={};
    toAdd[s]=[];
```

How do I add `toAdd` to `this.state.items`?

UPDATE,

I think I got it working with the following:

```
var ourLists = this.states.items;
ourlists[s] = [];

 and then just setState.
```

I'm having trouble understanding the basic syntax of two lines:

```
toAdd[s] = [];  // is this just the way you specify a key value pair where the value is an array?
```

Comment: Yeah, just turn the arrow function into a regular function. Object.assign essentially "adds" and combines properties of the passed objects, compiling them into one.

Comment: sorry, I'm lost.  How would a beginner do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/MooMee/pen/mqvbPX?editors=1010) for you.
In general if you want to add new value to an object in your state, you **can't** do both at the same time, first you need to create the key then to give it a value. (this would be the old way):

```
var obj = {};
obj["newKey"] = [];
obj.newKey = [<some value>]
```

Now you can use `Object.assign()` which will help you adding a new property to an object, while keeping things in order. By order I mean:

```
Object.assign(
 {<typically new empty object>},
 {<the old object you want to change>},
 {<the new field + value to add>}
)
```

**Make sure to keep the order otherwise old value would overwrite new!!!.**

After you've done that you can set the value of the new state to the new object you've created.

Comment: `assign` doesn't just overwrite old values, it depends on the order of objects passed to it, as they're assigned in order.

If you pass an empty object as the first argument you'll avoid modifying any existing objects.

Comment: True, I'll add it :)

Comment: so the old way is:   var ourList = this.state.items;
                 ourList[s] = [];
                               this.setState( { items: ourList } );

Comment: In general yes, but also added to the answer.